# Angularjs, update values in an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, datetime

This is my array

```
someArray = [

          {
              city: colombo1,
              text: 'name1',
              newArray[ date: 2018-09-29T18:30:00.000Z, discription: 'none']
          }

          {
              city: colombo2,
              text: 'name',
              newArray[ date: 2018-10-10T07:03:43.835Z, discription: 'none']
          }

      ];
```

I want to update my array as below

```
someArray = [

          {
              city: colombo1,
              text: 'name1',
              newArray[ date: Sun Sep 30 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), discription: 'none']
          }

          {
              city: colombo2,
              text: 'name',
              newArray[ date: Wed Oct 10 2018 14:05:27 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), discription: 'none']
          }

      ];
```

I try to use `map()` to update my array. But I cannot understand the logic to do that. Can anyone please help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

i hope newArray is an array which has 'date' as index,

```
for(var i=0;i<someArray.length;i++){
  someArray[i].newArray['date'] = new Date(someArray[i].newArray['date']).toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want use map try something like this:

```
var mappedArray = someArray.map(function(item){
    item.newArray['date'] = convertDate(item.newArray['date']); 
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/83sqfxc0/1/